# If I open up <img> src in a new window, a blank window opens

Tags: html, image, https

When I try to open up the source of a small .png, only a black screen is available.

I need to copy these images. How do I go about this?

The Example:

Website
https://www.property24.com/property-values/160-alexander-street/brooklyn/pretoria/gauteng/c3dhjiriz2h3ss3nezycf2iqpbnejigrnvvtx4z2vrsw6wztd2wq

Image

```
 <img src="/ListingReadOnly/GetImage?id=8ab6ea84-83d9-4114-b73e-15edffa72d74" alt="Last sales price of the property">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add more details, Open - where? Copy - where?

Comment: So, I open the property24 webpage. Inspect the image. Copy the link address for that image. Paste that link address into a new Chrome tab. I would expect the image to show up on that new Chrome tab, however, only an empty black screen shows up.

Answer (score 0):

The path to your image in your example code seems to be a relative path so copying and pasting it (the path) into anther tab wouldn't work. If you're using Chrome try one of these:

1. Right click on the image and select "Copy Image"
2. Right click on the image, select "Save image as...", (Image downloads), click the  down arrow on the right side of the download and select "Show in Folder", Selected the image in the open explorer and copy it as you would a normal file
3. Right click on the image, select "Open in new tab", copy it from there
4. Left click on the image and drag it to your desktop (windows), copy it from there

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked up the source of the link that you've provided, I can't find any image of ID: 8ab6ea84-83d9-4114-b73e-15edffa72d74. It probably might be some server side change.

Looking at Alt of the image, I hope, you're looking for the image next to the text: "Last sold price:"

There's no need for you to dig up and find the source. Just right clicking on that image in Chrome gave me an option to open it in new tab. From there you can save it or copy-paste, or whatever.

**EDIT:** This is the URL of the image I got: https://www.property24.com/ListingReadOnly/GetImage?id=1e82e647-2b26-4dfe-a519-904be5215045

**EDIT EDIT:** Yes, clicking on the link I gave now also loads a black screen. So, the best way around this is to open the link of the webpage (https://www.property24.com/property-values/160-alexander-street/brooklyn/pretoria/gauteng/c3dhjiriz2h3ss3nezycf2iqpbnejigrnvvtx4z2vrsw6wztd2wq), right click on that image and open it in new tab (or directly sve it) and upload it somewhere else to create its URL.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

So, let me get things straight. You want to get the map image? if you are using Chrome: You can right click and click "open image in new tab". you then can download the image from there.

[Image](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=690x368&sensor=false&center=-25.759945%2C%2028.241033&key=AIzaSyC2RktftcJdFvtKiGUWgQdEtRk2Jq1mNYg&zoom=15&markers=icon:https://www.property24.com//Content/images/Optimized/Maps/map_pin.png?52fc2c%7C-25.759945,%2028.241033)